# How to determine if a method in a particular class is being called from a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, jms

I have a jar file, it has its own source and object code, but is also bundled with its dependent jars within the master jar file

I want to find out if a given method in a given Class is being called by the jar, and which of the dependent jars bundled within the master jar contains that class.

Specifically, I want to find out if the code is calling the getProviderVersion from either MQCOnnectionData or ConnectionData class

So I want to see if the code uses which or either of these, and which of the dependent jars within the master jar contains the methods

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange question, but you can set breakpoint on method `getProviderVersion()` and run debugger. If the program will stop on the method, check whether the call was from interests you jar.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can not use a debugger in the configuration I have.  Any other ideas ?

Comment: Add logger to `getProviderVersion()`, recompile  and run with modified code. Then check your logs...